# How to make React/Socket.IO app reachable from outside

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sockets

I'm struggling to make my app (React + Node.js + Socket.IO) running in local, reachable from outside.
I expose my 3000 port via tunneling (ngrok) but my socket connection listens on 3001.
After having my port exposed port I obtain a Url, which used from another pc not on my network, makes my React App reachable but without the socket functionalities.
If I try to make socket listening on 3000 the whole app stops working on local aswell.
I'm new on this so I puzzles me how to make it work
The final goal is to host the React App from my PC, using it to chat via browser from the same PC with another one not on the same network.
I just want to make it work from my pc, so no external hosting from third parts.
Any idea?

Index.js /server

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(`User Connected: ${socket.id}`);

  socket.on("join_room", (data) => {
    socket.join(data);
  });

  socket.on("send_message", (data) => {
    socket.to(data.room).emit("receive_message", data);
  });
});

server.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("SERVER IS RUNNING");
});
```

App.js (React) /client

```js
import "./App.css";
import io from "socket.io-client";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3001");

function App() {
  //Room State
  const [room, setRoom] = useState("");

  // Messages States
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [messageReceived, setMessageReceived] = useState("");

  const joinRoom = () => {
    if (room !== "") {
      socket.emit("join_room", room);
    }
  };

  const sendMessage = () => {
    socket.emit("send_message", { message, room });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("receive_message", (data) => {
      setMessageReceived(data.message);
    });
  }, [socket]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        placeholder="Room Number..."
        onChange={(event) => {
          setRoom(event.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <button onClick={joinRoom}> Join Room</button>
      <input
        placeholder="Message..."
        onChange={(event) => {
          setMessage(event.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <button onClick={sendMessage}> Send Message</button>
      <h1> Message:</h1>
      {messageReceived}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a quick review of your situation:

- React app is running on port 3000 on your local computer ;
- NodeJS app with WebSocket server is running on port 3001 on your local computer.

You want your app to work on your local network, therefore both the React App and the WebSocket server must be available.

If you try to run both on the same port it will fail (two different applications can't listen on the same port).

The idea then is to ngrok both the WebSocket server and the React App launching ngrok for localhost:3000 et localhost:3001 (you will need to adapt CORS and React WebSocket URL though).
Which raise a second problem, I suppose you can't use ngrok with two endpoints (localhost:3000 and localhost:3001) on the free tier.

A simple solution: you can tell React CRA and NodeJS to accept request from network using 0.0.0.0 as host:

- for CRA it's the HOST variable (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/)
- for NodeJS: you can use the host argument to `server.listen`.

You will still need to adapt the CORs and REACT app configuration though.

Comment: Thanks but I did not undestand yet. Do I have to change:
Server side:
const PORT = 3000;
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {  cors: {    origin: "*",  },});
server.listen(PORT, () => { console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);});

React side: (package.json)
"scripts": {
    "start": "HOST=0.0.0.0 ADDRESS PORT=3000 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },

Or am I missing something?

Comment: You should launch the server with :
- `PORT=3001 HOST=0.0.0.0 npm run start`
And the React App with: 
- `PORT=3000 HOST=0.0.0.0 npm run dev`